# nginx how to block this lightweight DDoS

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have a movies related Wordpress site running with a large database(around 150k posts).
For some days during the important traffic hours we get hit by a small scale DDoS which slows down the site extremely or even causes it to go down for a few minutes.

This DDoS attack targets the search function of our site which uses lots of resources due to that many posts.

As I'm not very familiar with regex in nginx, I wanted to know how I should block those requests of this pattern(I censored the IPs but it is clearly a botnet):

```
107.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [26/Jan/2015:20:48:24 +0000] "GET /?s=Dog%20Days%20Double%20Dash HTTP/1.1" 200 12921 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firef$
79.xx.xxx.xxx - - [26/Jan/2015:20:48:29 +0000] "GET /?s=Dog%20Days%27%27 HTTP/1.1" 200 12908 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
77.xxx.xxx.xx - - [26/Jan/2015:20:48:48 +0000] "GET /?s=DragonBall%20Z%3A%20Movie%206 HTTP/1.1" 200 12921 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
68.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [26/Jan/2015:20:48:51 +0000] "GET /?s=DragonBall%20Z%3A%20Movie%207 HTTP/1.1" 200 12920 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
87.1xx.xxx.xxx - - [26/Jan/2015:20:49:02 +0000] "GET /?s=DragonBall%20Z%3A%20Super%20Saiyajin%20Songoku HTTP/1.1" 200 12944 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
```

it is clearly an attack because the search string consists of some random Words with those %20 whitespaces between. if a user enters a search string with white spaces, wordpress replaces them with "+" signs. so it would look like this "/s=word1+word2+word3...

The example i provided is just a snippet of those requests. In the access log are hundreds of those requests after each other. sometimes up to 30 per second. Additionally those ips come from all over the world, wheras around 90% of my visitors come from german speaking countries

I thought about maybe blocking those "%20" as whitespaces that come from valid search requests of users will be replaced with "+" by Wordpress

here is another snippet of the access log with full ips:

```
84.120.1.249 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:49 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%3A%20Film%2005 HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
93.116.219.207 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:49 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%20Movie%207 HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
77.198.194.177 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:49 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%20Movie%2004 HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
220.135.124.201 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:49 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%20Kai HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
93.199.176.64 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:49 +0000] "GET /?s=Detektiv%20Conan%20Film%202%20Das%2014.%20Ziel HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
122.117.101.17 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:49 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%20Movie%2003 HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
81.48.128.58 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:49 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%20Movie%207 HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
94.248.215.168 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:49 +0000] "GET /?s=Detektiv%20Conan%20Film%2015%20Die%2015%20Minuten%20der%20Stille HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
87.97.29.170 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:49 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%3A%20Dead%20Zone HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
79.5.183.62 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:50 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%3A%20Film%2010 HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
2.8.52.254 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:50 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%20Movie%208 HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
151.32.105.251 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:50 +0000] "GET /?s=Detektiv%20Conan%20Film%2015%20Die%2015%20Minuten%20der%20Stille HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
88.167.158.37 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:50 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%20Movie%2012 HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
175.142.209.188 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:50 +0000] "GET /?s=Detektiv%20Conan%20Movie%202%3A%20Das%2014.%20Ziel HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
24.150.82.126 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:50 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%3A%20Film%2005 HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
80.99.0.149 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:50 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%3A%20Dead%20Zone HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
109.192.242.158 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:50 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%20Kai HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
109.61.92.185 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:50 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%20Movie%208 HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
109.89.45.188 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:50 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%20Movie%2012 HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
188.129.122.30 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:50 +0000] "GET /?s=Detektiv%20Conan%20Film%2015%20Die%2015%20Minuten%20der%20Stille HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
87.218.93.189 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:50 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%3A%20Film%2004 HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
178.7.131.219 - - [25/Jan/2015:20:21:50 +0000] "GET /?s=Dragon%20Ball%20Z%3A%20Dead%20Zone HTTP/1.1" 502 383 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0"
```

Comment: You should be aware that WordPress does not replace spaces with + or %20, the browser does this, and both are equally valid.

Comment: The correct way to solve this problem is to implement rate limiting, and not your broken solution that will lock out many legitimate users.

Comment: as far as i know rate limiting works only with unique ips but not with botnets. or am i wrong?

Answer (score -1):

ok finally i was able to block this DDoS simply by adding this to my nginx vhost config:

```
if ($arg_s ~ %20) { return 403; }
```

Comment: %20 is the standard http way of encoding a space, and most browsers will do it by default. Using that regx will probably drop a huge percentage of requests, including lots of legitimate ones.

Comment: well i know that %20 is a way space encoding. howewer nowadays most browsers will encode spaces with a "+". I´ve also checked my acess logs of previous days. i´ve found none request of a valid user to the search script containing %20 as space encoding. all those requests encoded it with a '+'. So maybe this way of protection will affect 1% of valid visitors. I can live with that as those daily DDoS during main traffic affected all visitors. But well if you have a better aproach of blockin this, please tell it to me ;)

Comment: Personally I'd have gone for blocking Dragon%20Ball, as much of the DDoS traffic seems to start with this. Then you would only affect anyone who had an old browser and was searching for that series. However, the person performing the DDoS might notice just these were being blocked after a while and change their parameters. Either way, I'd keep an eye on the numbers of requests hitting this, in case the DDoS changes or goes away :)